# How to search string not in char array using LinQ

Tags: c#, list, linq

```
List<string> words = new List<string> { "abc", "acb", "cba", "cb a", "abf", "sea", "aba", "so ap", "a b c" }; 
string allowedChars = "abc";
```

I want to check invalid charachters in list string. I try use IndexOfAny() but IndexOfAny() does not check white space. How to check string which contains invalid charachters?

The result I want: "cb a", "abf", "sea", "so ap", "a b c"

Comment: Should `"bcaa"` be returned? `""`? `"a"`? `"ac"`?

Comment: @mjwills "", "a", "ac" should not be return

Comment: @mjwills "bcaa" should not be return too

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
var invalid = words.Where(w => !w.All(allowedChars.Contains));
```

It checks for every word if there is at least one char in it which is not contained in `allowedChars`.

This is the same but little bit more verbose:

```
var invalid = words.Where(w => w.Any(c => !allowedChars.Contains(c)));
```

Both stop execution if they found the first char that is not contained.

As Juharr has noted, if there are many characters allowed you could make it more efficient by using a `HashSet<char>` instead of the `String`:

```
var alloweCharSet = new HashSet<char>(allowedChars);
```

Comment: Depending on the number of characters it might be a good idea to put them into a `HashSet`.

Answer (score 3):

Returns all words that contain any other characters than allowedChars:

```
var result = words.Where(w => w.Except(allowedChars).Any());
```

While this gives the desired result, it was pointed out that this will, by calling Except, create a new `Set` for `allowedChars` for every `word` in the list. This might not give the best performance.

Comment: If you are going to use `Except` you'd be better to put `allowedChars` into a `HashSet` and then use `Contains` - perf will be much better than this. _Since this code is effectively creating a `HashSet` per word rather than a single `HashSet` - https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs#L899 ._